# Function whose domain is strictly included in its range

Tags: reductions, undecidability, semi-decidability

Hi I'm doing some exercices on reductions and one of them is like this:

[image]

My problem rather than doing the reduction is understanding it. For the positive case I want that if Mx(x) never stops then p's domain has to be strictly included in q's domain which has to be stricly included in p's range. Am I wrong? Therefore Dom(p) has to be stricly included in Range(p), right?

Let's forget about reductions for a moment, my problem here is: is there any function $f(x)$ whose domain is strictly included in its range?

We would want to have $Dom(f(x)) = \{1\}$ and $Range(f(x)) = \{1, 2\}$ That would mean that 1's image has to be 1 **AND** 2 :/

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks for your time and have a nice day! :D

Answer (score 1):

Without getting to the technicality of codomain/range/image and surjective functions, the property you ask for can surely happen. For instance,

$$f(x) = 2x$$

defined over the domain interval $[0,1]$, has the image $[0,2]$. This should not happen over finite domains.

Answer (score 0):

You are completely violating the rules for a function. For any element x in the domain there is only one image. This is the thing which differentiates a function from a relation. In a relation it is perfectly valid for an element to be related to b as well as c.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I'm trying to say, am I undersanting something wrong or is not possible to solve the problem, that is, having a function like the example I've given which is obviously wrong :/

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem:

[image]

It did seem impossible to make a deterministic function with the described properties (since only integer numbers are allowed). The trick of this exercise is using infinite domains.